# How to use springMVC and ajax to upload a pictrue,why there is error 500 in my program?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

```html
package com.restaurant.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Map;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/restaurant")
public class HeadPorUploadPre {

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/uploadPreview",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Map<String,Object> uploadPre(@RequestBody MultipartFile up, HttpSession session, HttpServletRequest request){
        String path = session.getServletContext().getRealPath("/images/headPortrait/headPortraitPre");
        String fileName = up.getOriginalFilename();
        String extensionName = fileName
                .substring(fileName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);

        String newFileName = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())
                + "." + extensionName;

        File targetFile = new File(path, newFileName);

        if(!targetFile.exists()){
            targetFile.mkdirs();
        }

        //save
        try {
            System.out.println("save");
            up.transferTo(targetFile);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#up").change(function () {
        $.ajaxFileUpload({
            type: 'post',
            url: '/restaurant/uploadPreview',
            fileElementId: 'up',
            dataType:"json",
            contentType:"application/json",
            async: true,
            success: function (data) {
                for(var i in data){
                    console.log(i);
                    console.log(data[i]);
                }
            },
            error: function (jqXHR) {
                console.log(jqXHR.status);
            }
        })
    })
})
```

I want to upload a pictrue to check its size and its type,but in controller I print file.getOriginalFilename(), I get nothing.And I had already add multipartResolver in applicationContext.xml.So where is my error?

Comment: take a look at your url

Comment: I guess you should set proper content type. Since you are not sending jsonn object, it should be multipart/form-data

Comment: If you see error 500, you will very likely see a stacktrace in your log file. It will tell you what you did wrong. Much better than us making WAGs.

Answer (score 0):

Change the content type to `"multipart/form-data"`

Comment: just remove the content type, ajaxFileUpload will add automaticly

Comment: `@RequestBody("{fileKeyName}") MultipartFile up` and also change the param to this, fileKeyName is the file param name.

Comment: Thanks,I have resolved it,I had an error in <input name/>